# Share a Cookie between Rails and Jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, jekyll

I am currently writing a Jekyll blog for my website.  It will live under a subdomain of the site (blog.site.com vs site.com) and I would like to be able to tie into the main website's login system (Rails 3.0 running with the Sorcery gem).

My use case is that I want to be able to change the blog's Navbar depending on the user's login status:

- If the user is logged in then it should show his/her profile image and username with a drop down of options
- Otherwise it should show a signup / login link

How do I go about doing this? I looked through http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html and my site doesn't handle any cookies logic, it is all handled via the Sorcery gem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The cookie approach

Have a look at cookies in your browser after logging in to your site. (In firefox you find them in Preferences->Security->Delete cookies) Rails default behavior is to set a cookie with the session id. You can pick this one up on your jekyll site to understand is the user is logged in or not. Since jekyll uses static pages you'll need to do this with javascript.

If the user is logged in you also need to communicate profile image and username via cookies. Just use the guide you linkes to to set cookies from rails and then pick them up with javascript on the jekyll side.

#### Alternatives

One alternative would be to iframe the navbar from the rails site. Just expose a route in your rails site that returns a partial with the information you need. Important of course to check if the user is logged in!

Another alternative is to use javascript to call an api in the rails app that gives back some json that can be used to render the navbar.